# Custom MessagePack formatter reusing existing formatters

Tags: c#, serialization, msgpack

I have a complex class (inheritance... generics... abstract base class...) for which I would like to create a custom messagepack formatter. This is not an issue as such, I just need to implement IMessagePackFormatter<>. But some properties of this class return other classes that can be serialized by a standard messagepack formatter without any issues. In addition, they are big, with many trivial properties. Manually serializing them would be a lot of trivial code, also it is error-prone, because in other places these classes are automatically serialized. So, is it possible to make a custom serializer, which would "delegate" serializing of certain parts to a standard one?

Comment: Are you using a specific MessagePack nuget package?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using https://www.nuget.org/packages/MessagePack it should automatically handle that with the `CompositeResolver` or one of the built-in resolvers.  See https://morioh.com/p/3cf5d2226b08

> CompositeResolver composes several resolvers and/or formatters together in an ordered list, allowing reuse and overriding of behaviors of existing resolvers and formatters.

```cs
// Do this once and store it for reuse.
var resolver = MessagePack.Resolvers.CompositeResolver.Create(
    // resolver custom types first
    ReactivePropertyResolver.Instance,
    MessagePack.Unity.Extension.UnityBlitResolver.Instance,
    MessagePack.Unity.UnityResolver.Instance,

    // finally use standard resolver
    StandardResolver.Instance
);
var options = MessagePackSerializerOptions.Standard.WithResolver(resolver);

// Each time you serialize/deserialize, specify the options:
byte[] msgpackBytes = MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(myObject, options);
T myObject2 = MessagePackSerializer.Deserialize<MyObject>(msgpackBytes, options);
```

In the `IMessagePackFormatter.Serialize()` method you can then write your values and serialize the custom objects like this:

```cs
writer.WriteRaw(MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(myobject.Something, options);
```

Comment: I know how to use resolvers, the pb is different.
Let's say, I'm implementing IMessagePackFormatter<MyClass> for my custom formatter.
In 
Serialize(ref MessagePackWriter writer, MyClass value, MessagePackSerializerOptions options)
method I do 
writer.Write(value.Field1)... Write(value.Filed2)...
And my value.FieldN is a complex class which I don't want to manually write as a sum of its subfields (there'll be many). I'd like to delegate it to existing formatters. Is it possible to do it? Somehow say "This field you serialize is a standard way".

Comment: @ElDog Can you use writer.WriteRaw(MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(myobject.Something, options); ?

Comment: this may be a solution I'm looking for, going to try.